# Refresh agenda after marking task as done

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Hello I am new to Emacs and Org Mode and I am trying to setup my agenda view.
If I mark a task as done with `t` I need to `r` refresh the agenda view to see the new status.

I understand from the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html#index-org_002dagenda_002dtodo) that the line below ensures that the new status is also visible in the agenda

```
(setq org-agenda-todo t)
```

What do I need to add to make this work?

**Code**

```
(require 'org)
(add-to-list 'org-modules 'org-habit t)


(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)

(org-agenda-list)
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/gtd/inbox.org"
                         "~/gtd/projects.org"
                         "~/gtd/habits.org"
                         "~/gtd/tickler.org"))

(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO(t)" "WAIT(w@/!)" "|" "DONE(d!)" "CANCELED(c@)")))

(setq org-use-fast-todo-selection t)
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
(setq org-log-done t)
(setq org-agenda-todo t)
```

Comment: that doc is saying the the key `t` calls the function `org-agenda-todo`, which should by default update the header "TODO" to the next state.  So, in your agenda view, after pressing `t`, you don't see the TODO change to DONE (or whatever the next state is)?

Comment: I have done something wrong with `(setq org-todo-repeat-to-state t)` Hope to post the answer later

Comment: It seems to work, but I don't know why I it works without [org-todo-repeat-to-state](https://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html)